# How to upload JSON data file from Mac desktop to RStudio?

Tags: r, json, rstudio, jsonlite

I have a data set on my mac laptop's desktop labelled "code.json" and I want to upload it into RStudio as json file using jsonlite. How do I do that? I thought I had to find the location of the code but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you tried? Where exactly is the JSON file located? What is the current working directory of your RStudio session. Because it sounds like the JSON file and RStudio are on the same machine, i probably wouldn't call this an "upload." You just need to open/load the file in much the same way you would do with any text or CSV file you are importing. When something "doesn't work" please be sure to include the exact error message you get. That will help us know more precisely what's going on.

Comment: the JSON file is currently on my mac desktop home screen. I am trying to make a Sankey diagram with this data so first i did the following code:

Comment: install.packages('curl')     install.packages(networkD3) then I ran the library. I then tried to open the file however due to the following code I am instructed to use it does not want me to load it as a CSV file. Following all the methods suggested below, I have the same error message given which is: Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       homeworkcode.json
             (right here) ------^

Comment: if i Ise the sewed code too it says : Error in setwd("/Users/Jasmine/Desktop") : 
  cannot change working directory

Comment: I think my main issue is my pathway to the file on my desktop. I have tried literally everything and dont understand whyy isn't working. Ive done "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/file name" and ive tried different variations of this. Any insight is appreciated

Comment: On a Mac try `setwd(“~/Desktop”)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your working directory already set to desktop

```
j <- fromJSON("code.json")
```

If not, then

```
j <- fromJSON("/Users/username/Desktop/code.json")

# or

setwd("/Users/username/Desktop")
j <- fromJSON("code.json")
```

Your json file is now stored in R object `j`

Comment: If i receive the following errors for the first 2 methods: Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       homeworkcode.json
              (right here) ------^                                                                                        what does that mean. For the last suggestion I get this error: Error in setwd("/Users/Jasmine/Desktop") : 
  cannot change working directory